# Relative vs. absolute path for a changelog.xml file in a Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

If I run:

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath="C:\path\to\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar" --changeLogFile=c:\path\to\project\db\db-changelog.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaname" --username=user --password=pass update
```

it outputs:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file C:\path\to\project\db\db-changelog.xml was not found in the configured search path:
```

but if I cd into project directory and run the command by providing `db-changelog.xml` path as a relative one:

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath="C:\path\to\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar" --changeLogFile=db\db-changelog.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaname" --username=user --password=pass update
```

then it works fine.

Why?

[Using Liquibase 4.21.1]